# Nested GridView with Expand and Collapse feature - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview inside gridview with expand and collapse feature. I have followed this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx) to achieve this. Initially gridview shows a plus icon and if user clicks on it it turns to minus icon and will show nested gridview. Now I want to set the initial icon as minus if there is no data in nested gridview.And nothing should happens when clicking on this minus icon. If there is data on nested gridview it should behave as normal as now.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
            <div class="userGrid">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
             </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
</Columns>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
});
$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
});
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=gvCustomers.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('.userGrid table tr').length > 0) {
            //need to set plus icon  
                alert("Yes,gvOrders has row");
           } else {
                //need to set minus icon without click event
                alert("no,gvOrders has no  row");
           }
       });//end of loop

   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a RowDataBound event already. Why not replace the image with an Image Control.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/plus.png" />
```

Then you can check if the nested GridView has any data and change the ImageUrl accordingly. Then you can also easily make sure the image has a pointer cursor if it can be expanded.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image img = e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image;

        if (nestedSource == 0) {
            img.ImageUrl = "images/min.png";
        }
        else
        {
            img.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer");
        }
    }
}
```